# Is multiplication normally/binomially distributed?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was thinking about the binomial formula in the context of coin flips and got to thinking about the reason that even though HHHHHHHHHH is just as likely to occur as a sequence as HHHHHTTTTT, 5 heads and 5 tails has a much higher probability. I concluded that there are many more permutations or possible ways to get 5 heads and 5 tails than 10 heads or 10 tails.

In the case of 10 flips, we see that the symmetry scenario (5H and 5T) yields the greatest number of permutations (252), followed by 4 and 6 of each (210), 3 and 7 (120), 8 and 2 (45), etc...the pattern being that the decrease is non-linear, where the further away from symmetry, the greater the decrease from one distribution to the next.

The shape of the binomial distribution curve then made a lot of sense.

I then remembered that multiplication follows a similar pattern if we for ex consider all the ways to multiply the positive integers that add up to 10, as in: 
10*0 = 0 
9*1 = 9 
8*2 = 16 
7*3 = 21 
6*4 = 24 
5*5 = 25

We see that symmetry again yields the highest value, and that the differences between distributions away from symmetry increase more and more: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc...

The pattern looks similar to that of the binomial distribution, so I wondered: Does the multiplication example follow a binomial distribution as well? If not, is there a name for that kind of distribution?

Comment: The two curves have vaguely similar shapes, up and then symmetrically down. But looked at more closely, they are very different. The multiplication curve $y=x(a-x)$ has a broader flattish area in the middle, and decays less rapidly in the tails.  It really does not look "bell-shaped."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phenomenon is similar. Consider maximizing $x\left(y-x\right)$ with respect to $x$ (i.e. holding $y$ fixed). Note that
$$x\left(y-x\right)=xy-x^{2}$$
is a parabola with a maximum at $x^{\star}=y/2$. In your example, $y=10$, and $x^{\star}=10/2=5$.

[image]

Now consider the binomial curve $\binom{x}{y}$ for fixed $y$. The shape of this curve is different, and the maximum is much larger. For example, $\binom{x}{10}$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Except that the curves are quite different. The binomial curve is bell shaped while the multiplication curve is an inverted parabola, much wider.